# Multiple side by side bullet points

Tags: bullets

Ive seen the two column example but im trying to do the following:
[image]

To the following code

```
\section{Key Skills}
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
    \task \textbf{Data Cleansing & Transformation} 
    \task \textbf{Statistical & Data Analysis}
    \task \textbf{Feature Design & Implementation}
    \task \textbf{Machine Learning}
    \task \textbf{Mathematical Programming}
    \task \textbf{Deep Learning}
    \task \textbf{}
\end{tasks}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use something like `\textbullet~foo \textbullet~boo \textbullet~lipsum` manually.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: thank you for the welcome @Zarko, so fara, following tasks


 https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks-manual.pdf

 I am able to produce several bullets in one line, close but no cigar. I still need to group them together, as they appear in columns, and not side by side

Comment: @Fabianm, link is not useful. It can become dead after while, so please, edit your question and add in it what you try so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please, always provide a MWE (minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which can be compiled as it is.
- In it provide what you do yourself and indicate where you stuck.
- A possible solution is use `enumitem` package and define `inlinelist`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{inlinelist}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist*[inlinelist,1]{label=\textbullet,
                        itemjoin={{ \ }}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
    \centerline{\textbf{KEY SKILLS}}

\begin{inlinelist}
    \item Data Cleasing  \& Transfpormation
    \item Statistical \& Data Analisys
    \item Feature Design \& Implementation
    \item some other text
    \item two words
    \item Technique Validation
    \item Business Development
\end{inlinelist}

\medskip
Standard list
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @daleif, ups, I use one my old answer where list was `enumerate`. Corrected now. Thank you very much to pointed this out.